# UWP Windows IoT Failed to Generate FFU for RaspberryPi

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to generate FFU image for my appx.

However, it fail with the message Error: Failed to create FIP Packages
 [image: Error: Failed to create FIP Packages].

I checked the log and seems like there are missing .cab files. 
[image: Missing .cab files]

I tried to run 'New-IoTCabPackage All' again and it doesn't work.

I also noticed that IOTCORE_VER is empty. I am not sure how to make it right.

[image: IoT Version]

I have followed lab1a & 1b instructions.

Please help.

Update (03-04-2019)
I managed to flash the FFU but unable to see my appx in the apps manager [image: apps manager].

Update (04-07-2019)
I regenerated the cab & FFU and manage to see the appx_myuwpapp in the list but once i flashed the FFU on raspberry pi 3, the wifi & ethernet are not working.
[image]
[image]

Update -2 (04-07-2019)
When i import IoTBSP, found out that there is no FM files in RPI_BSP. Is this the reason wifi & ethernet isn't working?
[image]

Comment: Hi mylim, please let me know if my answer doesn't help for your issue.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT thanks. I was not able to test until yesterday. I noticed that my appx didn't appear in under the `apps manager`. Is there anything that i missed.

Comment: Check the OEMInput.xml to see if there is a feature ID of your application.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT can i know how check OEMInput.xml ?

Comment: Find the OEMInput.xml in path: \[your workspace]\Build\arm\ProductA\Test\ProcessedFiles\, open it and check if there is a feature ID, for example, APPX_MYUWPAPP in  [Lab 1b](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/deploy-your-app-with-a-standard-board).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I regenerated the cabpackage & FFU and manage to see the appx listed. However, I am using Rasp Pi 3 once I flashed the FFU, the wifi & ethernet doesn't work. Can advise.

Comment: Do you use Raspberry Pi 3B or 3B+? Have you ever tried the official pre-build image to see the wifi works? BTW, your initial issue is solved, please post new question for different issue instead of extending discussions in comments.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT i am using RaspPi 3B... prebuilt image download from IoT Core Dashboard works fine. I am not sure if the RSP_BSP i downloaded (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/bsphardware) is the issue.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFTwhen i import iotBSP .. i noticed that there is no FM files in RPI_BSP which i downloaded.

Comment: There are .inf, .sys and .wm.xml three kind of files in RPi_BSP. What do you mean of FM files?

Comment: Hi ... It worked! I had to regenerate everything all over again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also noticed that IOTCORE_VER is empty. I am not sure how to make it
>   right.

You need install Windows 10 IoT Core packages. You seem missed **step 4** of [Get the tools needed to customize Windows IoT Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/set-up-your-pc-to-customize-iot-core). For Raspberry Pi you need install this one: Windows_10_IoT_Core_Arm_Packages.msi.

[image]

After install complete you will find packages at the path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages\retail\arm\fre`

[image]